# Resample 16 bits depth mp3 to 32 bits depth

Tags: c

I have a problem that need to resample 16 bits depth to 32 bit depth mp3 in c program. any suggestion where I can find some repo as reference or web site to start with?

Comment: It's rather trivial to convert a 16-bit PCM stream to a 32-bit PCM stream, but neither MPEG 1 nor MPEG 2 audio encoding supports 32-bit encoding, so you would not be able to re-encode to MP3. I'm assuming you mean 32-bit per channel/per sample (stereo sample would be 64b).

Comment: yep, your guess is correct. 32-bit per channel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decode the MP3 into WAV or AIFF format with PCM coding, up-sample, then re-encode. [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org) is good for that.

However word of advice: You don't gain audio quality doing this, You only have 16 bits of information per sample, you can't add more to it. That's how information theory work.